# Exclude commits from Git hooks?

Tags: git, github, githooks, travis-ci

Is it possible to exclude certain commits from being pushed to a service hook on Github? For example, if I only edit the Readme file of a project, it makes no sense to re-test the entire application on Travis. Is there a way I can tell Git that that particular commit should not be sent to the Travis hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the Travis-related part: As explained in the [Travis docs](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/how-to-skip-a-build/) you can skip a build if you append `[ci skip]` to any of the commits you're going to push.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way to tell `git push` to skip hooks. You could, however, modify the hook to examine the received commit and only run the tests if a source file has been modified. How you do that depends on your project, but it could look for files with a certain extension, files in the `src/` directory, etc.